# How can I plot separate curves in python for different values of some constants without the lines joining?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Okay, so I'm trying to plot these two equations that are supposed to give me a range of curves with varying values for both of them.

What I want to do is plot
y = c1 * (1.05^k) + c2 * (0.55^k) * 5, vs y = c1 * (1.05^k) * 1.3 + c2 * (0.55^k)
for different values of c1 and c2. k is a value for the time, so I think k should also follow a range.

I've added my code, and I know where my problem is coming from (appending the lists basically), but can someone explain a simple way I can make it work otherwise and plot separate curves instead? Can I have the values of Y1 and Y2 be stored in a 2d array and work with that? Or should I make a function? (I tried making a function first but it wasn't working at all, so I sort of deleted that). But yeah, any suggestions or help on how to do this would be appreciated!

```
y1 = []
y2 = []

plt.figure(figsize= (16,10))
for c1 in range (-10, 10, 2):
    for c2 in range (-10, 10, 2):
        for k in range (0, 50):
            Y1 = c1*1.05**k + c2*(0.55**k)*5
            y1.append(Y1)
            Y2 = c1*(1.05**k)*1.3 + c2*(0.55**k)
            y2.append(Y2)

plt.plot(y1, y2)
```

Comment: How is matplotlib supposed to know you want multiple lines? All it can see is the two lists full of data, `y1` and `y2`. If you want separate curves, plot separate lists

Comment: A hint: look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978542/plot-multiple-functions-with-the-same-properties-in-matplotlib). Note how the `plot` statements in the second code sample in the question are *inside* the loop

Comment: Ahahah yeahhh, that's why I said I knew *exactly* what the problem was, I just couldn't figure out a way around it. BUT!!! The link you sent is really helpful!! Thank you!